Is there a uniform family of polynomials $f_p(x) =x^2 + a(p)x + b(p)$ such that $f_p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible and irreducible mod $p$?
Let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a positive prime number.
Is there a "uniform" family of polynomials $f_p(x) =x^2 + a(p)x + b(p)$ of degree two such that $f_p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is both irreducible and irreducible mod $p$ ?
If $p=4k+3$ for some positive integer $k$ then $f_p(x):=x^2+1$ does the trick and this does not even depend on $p$.
By the Minkowski bound (see,e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound), it is not possible to find such a polynomial which stays irreducible mod $p$ for all prime numbers $p$.
What happens if $p=4k+1$ ?
Doe we even have a "uniform" family of polynomials $f_p(x) =x^2 + a(p)x + b(p)$ which works for all (odd) primes $p$ ?
Edit: "uniform" should be interpreted as follows: are there $a(t),b(t)\in\mathbb{Z}[t]$ so that the statement is true?
Thank you for the help.

I don't understand what you're asking, because you don't define what you mean by "uniform". As you're written your question, the answer is yes, for every $p$ there exist $a(p)$ and $b(p)$ such that $x^2+a(p)x+b(p)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_p[x]$, and thus also in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Indeed, take $a(p)=0$ and $-b(p)$ a non-quadratic residue mod $p$. Presumably by "uniform" you mean some structure to $a(p)$ and $b(p)$. I guess that you could ask if there are $a(t), b(t)\in\mathbb Z[t]$ so that your statement is true.

Thank you, you're right. I have edited the question.

Giving a deterministic algorithm to find a non-QR modulo $p$, in a way faster than just trying values until you find one, is an open problem. There certainly shouldn't be a short formula that works.

No, this can't happen: For any polynomials $a,b \in \mathbb Z[t]$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f_p(x) := x^2 + a(p)x + b(p)$ is reducible modulo $p$.
Let $a_0 := a(0)$ and $b_0 := b(0)$. Then we have $f_p(x) \equiv x^2 + a_0x + b_0 \pmod p$, which is reducible (for odd $p$) if and only if $\Delta := a_0^2 - 4b_0$ is a square modulo $p$. But any integer $\Delta$ is a quadratic residue for infinitely many primes $p$, so $f_p$ will be reducible modulo infinitely many primes $p$.
